# SQL to update selected fields in table from view

Tags: mysql, sql, select, vlookup

I am new to this, so I apologize upfront for any confusion/frustration. I appreciate any help that I can get!

I have a table (**MainTable**) that I have created two views with (**GoodTable** and **BadTable**).

- Each table has 4 columns (*ID*, *UserID*, *key*, *value*).
- ID is the Primary Key, but
- UserID can repeat in several rows.

What I need to do in the **Main** table is find the *ID*s that are in the **BAD** table, and update the values from the *value* column of the **GOOD** table, based on a match of *UserID* **AND** a LIKE match with the *key* column, into the **MAIN** table.

I hope that makes sense.

I've tried:

```
UPDATE MainTable
SET value = (SELECT value FROM GoodTable
WHERE MainTable.UserID = GoodTable.UserID
AND MainTable.key LIKE "some%key%specifics");
```

This gets me ALMOST there, but the problem is if it doesn't find the LIKE key specifics, it returns a NULL value and I want it to keep it's original value if it's not in BadTable (BadTable is essentially all of the keys that match the LIKE key specifics). Obviously the above doesn't use BadTable, but I thought that might help me solve this (not the case, so far!)...

Here's a bit of an example:

```
MainTable:
ID    UserID    key    value
1     1         key1   good value
2     1         key2   bad value
3     1         key3   unrelated value
4     2         key1   good value
5     2         key2   bad value
6     2         key3   unrelated value

GoodTable:
ID    UserID    key    value
1     1         key1   good value
4     2         key1   good value

BadTable:
ID    UserID    key    value
2     1         key2   bad value
5     2         key2   bad value

What I want MainTable to change to:
ID    UserID    key    value
1     1         key1   good value
2     1         key2   good value
3     1         key3   unrelated value
4     2         key1   good value
5     2         key2   good value
6     2         key3   unrelated value
```

I also thought if there was something like a VLOOKUP (like in Excel) where I could say what to do if false, but I haven't been able to work that out either. I've tried some other things from researching other questions but I've spun myself dizzy now and decided to reach out for help :)

Lastly, I'm not sure if this matters or not, but this if for MySQL...

I'm sure I'm making this more complicated for myself than I need to, so I really appreciate any help anyone can provide!

**UPDATE**: per @Rabbit suggestion, this is the best I could come up with using the inner join (though I thought this would add to the MainTable, but I want to keep the number of rows in MainTable the same, just update that one field for the applicable rows..):

```
UPDATE MainTable
JOIN GoodTable ON MainTable.ID = GoodTable.ID
SET value = (SELECT value FROM GoodTable
WHERE MainTable.UserID = GoodTable.UserID
AND MainTable.key LIKE "some%key%specifics");
```

I'm sure this is an awful attempt but I am certainly a novice here!

I did manage to come up with a solution (though I am sure it is highly inefficient) -- please see answer below! (Thank you @DBug and @Rabbit for pointing me in the right direction!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said "**Main table is find the IDs that are in the BAD table, and update the values from the value column of the GOOD table, based on a match of UserID AND a LIKE match with the key column, into the MAIN table.**" so your sample result is wrong...

We will update the 2 and 5 ID from MainTable right? because it is in BadTable **BUT** 2 and 5 key is *Key 2* and there's no Key 2 on GoodTable.

If I will base on your answer. This might help you. Please check

```
UPDATE MainTable m 
INNER JOIN BadTable b ON m.id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN GoodTable g ON b.UserID = g.UserID 
SET m.value = g.value
```

A little fix on that. for the **key** you wanted

Comment: Hi @do_Ob! I think I follow the suggested code, and it makes sense, but I am getting "AS" and "INNER" syntax errors(??) so I can't test the results. :(  I'm sorry about the confusion with my problem. To try to clarify, some of the keys need to have the same value as others, but still retain their key identity. You are correct that 2 & 5 are not in GoodTable but their values need to be the same value as their USERID that is in the GoodTable (GoodTable should have distinct user IDs, whereas BadTable may have duplicate user IDs and MainTable surely will). I think your code does but I have errors.

Comment: just remove the **as**.. It will work also.. I already updated the query

Comment: BTW? what are you using?... I tried that on mysql and it's working with **as**.. your answer is not good.. you will create view just to update one table..

Comment: you are RIGHT!!! I was trying to do the query in a test mode, and I was getting those errors. So I just created a new test database with the original MainTable and used your suggested query -- and it **WORKS** (with or without the AS)!!! I knew there was a more efficient way to do this and THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!! Sorry about the confusion and frustration - I appreciate your patience and help @do_Ob!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Coalesce function, which returns the first non-null argument, giving it the value column from both tables, e.g.

```
UPDATE MainTable 
SET value = (SELECT COALESCE(GoodTable.value, MainTable.value) FROM GoodTable
WHERE MainTable.UserID = GoodTable.UserID
AND MainTable.key LIKE "some%key%specifics");
```

It will return GoodTable.value if it is not NULL, or MainTable.value if it is.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! It is still returning NULL for the ones that I did not want changed...Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I think maybe it is because the value that I don't want changed actually has something in there (therefore it isn't NULL), but it's just unrelated to what I want updated. I'm not sure though, if this is the reason this isn't working for me. Is there a way to make it skip the row in MainTable if there is not a match of IDs in BadTable, and if there is a match, then update that row in MainTable with the value in GoodTable? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a subquery, you can use a join in the UPDATE clause.

```
UPDATE Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.FieldName = Table2.FieldName
SET ....
WHERE ....
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this possible solution. I don't know why, but I couldn't get this one to work at all...I will continue to fiddle with it and keep you posted!

Comment: If you modify your post to include the newly updated SQL you're trying, maybe we can help spot the error.

Comment: You're right, that would probably help! I will modify it, but in the meantime I was able to come up with a way that DOES work for me (although I am sure there is a MUCH more efficient way to do it out there somewhere...). @Rabbit - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me, but note I needed to create yet another view (**MatchTable**):

```
UPDATE MainTable
SET value = COALESCE((SELECT value FROM MatchTable
WHERE MainTable.ID = MatchTable.ID
AND MainTable.key LIKE "some%key%specifics"),(SELECT value));
```

**MatchTable** is essentially taking the BAD rows (from **BadTable**) and updating their *value* with the GOOD values from **GoodTable**. Here is the code I used for that:

```
CREATE VIEW MatchTable AS
SELECT (BadTable.ID) AS "ID", (BadTable.UserID) AS "UserID", (BadTable.key) AS "key", (SELECT value FROM GoodTable
WHERE BadTable.UserID = GoodTable.UserID) AS "value" 
FROM BadTable
LEFT JOIN GoodTable
ON GoodTable.ID = BadTable.ID;
```

This resulted in the following data in **MatchTable**:

```
MainTable:
ID    UserID    key    value
2     1         key2   good value
5     2         key2   good value
```

For completeness of the solution, and if it happens to help anyone else, here are the queries that I used to create **GoodTable** and **BadTable**, respectively:

```
CREATE VIEW GoodTable AS
SELECT * FROM MainTable
WHERE key = "specific_key_term";

CREATE VIEW BadTable AS
SELECT * FROM MainTable
WHERE key LIKE "some%key%specifics";
```

Okay, to summarize, here is the entire process that I used to get the desired results in MainTable (as notated in the posted question):

1. Create **GoodTable** *view*
2. Create **BadTable** *view*
3. Create **MatchTable** *view*
4. Run *update* query to update **MainTable**
5. Celebrate wildly! (Just kidding - I can't help the nagging feeling that there has to be a better/more efficient way of doing this!) But seriously, **celebrate wildly**!

(Thank you again to @DBug for getting me on the right track for the update portion and to @Rabbit for getting me to the MatchTable!)